# Не получается сделать плавное раскрытие меню при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть меню, элементы которого содержат подменю хочу раскрывать при наведении на эти пункты и переворачивать стрелку вниз. Пишу код, но почему-то не выходит

```js
$('.menu').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul').toggle(400);
});
```

```css
.children {
  display: none;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a {
  overflow: auto;
  /* очищает обтекание */
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Subname 1</a>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Subname 2</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не верно используется метод [*siblings*](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) он ищет соседние элементы удовлетворяющие условию, а вам нужно искать дочерние, то есть, либо [*find*](https://api.jquery.com/find/) либо [*children*](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```js
$('.menu').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle(400);
});
```

```css
.children {
  display: none;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a {
  overflow: auto;
  /* очищает обтекание */
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Subname 1</a>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Subname 2</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а если я еще хочу добавить переворачивающуюся стрелку - вот такая же запись по ховеру `$(".menu>li.cat-item>a:after").css("content", "\f0d7");` не пройдет ?

Comment: @Вася, Нет, так как jQuery не может выбрать селектор `:after`

Comment: а каким образом тогда это решается?

Comment: @Вася, например навешиванием класса на элемент, и в зависимости от класса уже писать стиль с тем или иным content для after

Comment: делаю, но что-то пока не очень получается.. http://jsfiddle.net/EEgu7/25/

Comment: @Вася, ох, что-то мне это аккордеон напоминает :-) в jsfiddle у вас синтаксическая ошибка со скобочками, и забыли кавычки вокруг `a`, будет что-то вроде: http://jsfiddle.net/EEgu7/26/

Comment: единственное, стрелки переворачиваются везде, даже в меню, в которых подменю нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35501/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы рекомендовал делать так, до версии  jQuery 1.8 включительно, если версия выше то по примеру @Grundy

```
var toggleMenu = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('menu')) {
        return false;
    }
    $this.find('ul').toggle(400);
};
$(document).off('hover', '.menu', toggleMenu);
$(document).on('hover', '.menu', toggleMenu);
```

Данный кусок не нужно вешать на DomReady

Comment: а расскажите из каких соображений и не приведет ли это к неочевидным ошибкам? я не настолько хорошо в `js`, чтобы предвидеть такие моменты

Comment: @Вася, будьте аккуратнее с этим кодом, сначала он снимает **все** обработчики _hover_ с документа, и потом добавляет конкретный, то есть если выше был аналогичный код, но для другого селектора, например `'.mainmenu'` - То он перестанет работать

Comment: @Shnur, можете предоставить **рабочий** пример вашего кода? судя по всему он не работает, так как `$this` это элемент в классом `.menu`, следовательно `if ($this.hasClass('menu')) {` всегда `true` и управление до вызова `$this.find('ul').toggle(400);` никогда не доходит

Comment: @Grundy Прошу прощения, сейчас подправлю

Comment: [_Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions._](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - похоже начиная с 1.9 именно для hover такая запись не работает `$(document).on('hover',`

Comment: Да, проверил с 1.8 работает, а 2.1 уже нет

Comment: @Grundy, аналогично, этот код работает только до версии 1.8

Comment: @Shnur, ну так я про это и написал в комментариях, стоит наверное это в сам ответ добавить